# Регулярное выражение, ввод только цифр и не более 13

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

при вводе в поле, нужно запрещать ввод всего кроме цифр, и ввод не более 13 символов. Только цифры готово  `input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');`.

Как запретить ввод больше 13 цифр?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input.value.replace(/\D/g,'').substr(0,13)
```

`\D` - означает "НЕ цифра". И дополнительно берем строго не более 13 символов.

Comment: ну подходит, только хотел бы чистым регулярным выражением, и у меня вопрос чтоб вводить Только цифры(но эт я уже понял что заменить на \d)

Comment: @Karalahti Вместо substr можно конечно использовать второй replace, но именно второй ! одной регуляркой это сделать невозможно. Проблема в том, что как только будет удалена хотя бы одна буква, выполнение продолжится с этой точки, а подсчет символов для любых других ограничений с 1.

Comment: @Karalahti Одной регуляркой можно только проверить наличие не букв или более 13 символов, но использовать в replace такую регулярку не выйдет

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.number').live('keydown', function() {
    var checkingRegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d){1,13}$/g);
    return $(this).val().match(checkingRegExp) !== null;
});
```

Comment: `var checkingRegExp = /^\d{1,13}$/;` лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать квантор в котором указать диапазон

```
/^(\d){1,13}$/g
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/8h4akhwu/ не вышло

Comment: У вас функция не корректно была написана.

Comment: А вы проверяли то что вы написали?))) мне нужен ввод только цифр и не более 13)))

Comment: @Karalahti Так вот же пожалуйста https://regex101.com/
Проверьте мое регулярное выражение на правильность.

Comment: Я не про синтоксис ващего кода, а про вопрос, он был совершенно другой, ввод в поле только цифр и не более 13 символов в сторке! Mike подсказал, и стало работать https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/8h4akhwu/ попробуйте ввести что-нибуть в поле! Все кроме цифр отсекается и больше 13 символов не введете

Comment: @Karalahti Так я и подсказал регулярное выражение, позволяющее производить валидацию значения вводимого в поле.
Вы прочтите сначала тему вопроса, а потом возмущайтесь.
Хотели регулярное выражение ?? Получите, оно рабочее и использовать его значительно лучше, чем тот костыль, который вы мне пытаетесь продемонстрировать.